# matplotlib.pyplot imported but unused

Tags: python

I'm assuming this is an indentation error but for the life of me can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Would appreciate some help

```
def read_csv(filename):

    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)

        rain = []
        highest_correlated = []
        for row in reader:
            rain.append(float(row[1]))
            highest_correlated.append(float(row[2]))

    return rain, highest_correlated

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rain, highest_correlated = read_csv('correlaterain.csv')
    corr = find_corr_x_y(rain, highest_correlated)
print('Highest correlation: {0}'.format(corr))
scatter_plot(rain, highest_correlated)
```

Comment: unless somewhere else in your code you are using `plt` keyword that you've not posted here, you can remove (or comment out with prepending `#` before) the line `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Now I'm getting an undefined "find_corr_x_y" error on the 20th line

Comment: me too, because there is no function named`find_corr_x_y` in the code

Comment: Thanks anyways. I'm following an exercise off of a book and i'm not sure if I skipped a page or something because this is all that is provided.

Comment: I see, yeah you might have missed a step or something. search the book for a function that resembles `def find_corr_x_y`.

Comment: By chance is it this book? [Doing Math with Python](https://books.google.com/books?id=EvWbCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). If so, looks like it is on [page 235](https://books.google.com/books?id=EvWbCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA88&ots=NKPUuj8kbi&dq=highest_correlated.append(float(row%5B2%5D))&pg=PA235#v=onepage&q&f=false)